# How to update component from another component next js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a page with two components: table and header.

Page:

```
import Header from '@/components/header/header.js';
import Table from '@/components/table/table.js';

export default function TablePage() {

  return (
    <div>

      <Header />
      <main>
        <Table></Table>
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Header Component:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import styles from './header.module.css';

function search(e, router) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const string = e.target.querySelector('input').value;
  router.push('/table_page');
}

export default function Header () {
  const router = useRouter()

  return (
    <header className={styles.header}>
      <div className={styles.search}>
        <form onSubmit={(e) => {search(e, router)}}>
          <button type='submit'></button>
          <input type='search' placeholder='Type song or artist name'/>
        </form>
      </div>
    </header>
  )
}
```

Table Component:

```
import styles from './table.module.css';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import data from '@/youtube_data.json';

export default function Table() {

  let [myArray, updateMyArray] = useState([]);

  function handleSearchQuery(string) {
    updateMyArray(() => {
      const result = data.filter(item => item.title.match(string));
      return result;
    });
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    updateMyArray( () => {
      return data;
    });
  });

  return (
    <div className={styles.table}>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>
              Title
            </th>         
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {myArray.map(item =>
              <tr key={item.id}>
                <td>
                   {item.title}              
                </td>
              </tr>
            )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I need to somehow call the `handleSearchQuery` function by entering a query into `input` of the `header` component and upate the `table` component based on a string from the `input search` (it is a filter for searching through an array of data). How to do it?
I'm sure it's simple enough, but I'm stuck on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for a function at all.

Update the query param whenever the user types, in `Header`.
Read the query param using the hook, in the `Table`.

Flow:

1. User -> edits input in `Header` -> query param is updated.
2. `Table` re-renders, since it's using the `useRouter` hook.

That's it

Answer (score 0):

One way is in header component you set the query parameter when user searches. Since every page renders the `Header` in the table page you have `Header` and table. In the `Header`

```
export default function Header () {
  const router = useRouter()
  const [searchKey,setSearchKey=useState("")

  return (
    <header className={styles.header}>
      <div className={styles.search}>
        // when user submits the input set the query param
        <form onSubmit={() => {
          if (searchKey === "") return;
          // this will add query param
          router.push(`/?key=${searchKey}`);
          setLocation("");
        }}>
          <button type='submit'></button>
          // when user enters value, set the state value
          <input type='search' placeholder='Type song or artist name'
                 onChange={(e) => setSearchKey(e.target.value)}
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    </header>
  )
}
```

then you read the query param

```
// we named it key above
const { key } = router.query;
```

based on this value you update the `myArray` state value in `useEffect`

```
useEffect(()=>{
   updateMyArray(myArray.filter(item => item.title.match(key)))
   // [key] is dependency array
   // when "key" changes, your component will be updated and you will have filtered state value
},[key])
```